# Setting window in fullscreen switch others to second monitor

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, fullscreen

I have two monitors, whenever I launch a game in fullscreen, some of my other windows (chrome, skype, whatever) switch randomly to my second monitor and stay there when I quit the game, it doesn't always happen but it's always when they weren't minimized. It still happens when I turn off the second screen before launching the game.
I do not know if its specific to Windows 10.

Any way to prevent it ? Even a third party app will do.

Comment: Could you try windowed fullscreen and see if it still happens?

Comment: It doesn't -  I lose performance though

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I succeed by creating a new workspace on Windows 10 (Ctrl+Win+D) and play the game there.

Comment: How? I am trying the same thing, but when I create a new Desktop, I can only keep one in focus.

Comment: You create a new workspace, launch your game in that so that your others workspaces won't be affected by your game window. You only have one window in focus : your game.